# What type of distribution does this most closely resemble?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, distribution-identification

[image]

What type of distribution does this most closely resemble? I was thinking that this graph didn't really resemble any type of distribution.

Comment: What kind of data are these? Discrete or continuous? What is the context?

Comment: Looks like a mixture, reminds me of a tweedie distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution

Comment: Given there's an infinite number of distributions that are arbitrarily close to the data, without some restrictions, there's no useful way to answer the question beyond the one that matches the data exactly (i.e. the ecdf itself), which comes as close to the distribution of the data as you can get. Beware also of picking a distribution out of some arbitrary laundry list (as many programs have been written to do). Much better to think about (a) whether you need to choose one at all; (b) what you know about the variable (such as its support), ...

Comment: (c) whether the data you have represents a sample that it makes sense to apply a distribution to; (d) what models may have been used by experts for similar data previously, and (e) consider what you're trying to achieve by doing so (since that may well guide choices of distribution)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to come from https://rdrr.io/rforge/Lahman/man/Pitching.html, so sports data. One row per player per season since 1950. GS is games started.

This distribution probably doesn't have any nice name, because the distribution itself is not nice. That doesn't mean that it doesn't follow *any* distribution. Just describe it in some useful qualitative terms: it's bimodal, with approx 25% of the sample at 0, and a small local mode at 33. The max is (approx) 36. Really, the histogram (more of a barplot actually) tells the whole story.

Comment: It could perhaps be described as a mixture of two Poissons or Negative Binomials, possibly a three-component mixture with a point mass at 0.